# How do I get the standard Vim FTP command to work?

Tags: vim, ftp, macvim

When I do `vim ftp://[user@]machine/path` in Vim I get this error: `E683: File name missing or invalid pattern`. Why id Vim treating this command as a search pattern?

I'm getting the same error in MacVim and Terminal Vim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually you want to start Vim and then edit a file over ftp. Calling `vim` with a url may not work. You're supposed give a file path as argument to `vim` and that's what's causing the error.

Also, the error says:

> File name missing **or** invalid pattern

Vim is not treating it as a search pattern. Notice the "or". It happens that no file name is given.

Try starting vim and then:

```
:e ftp://[user@]machine/path
```