# How do I make files and folders over FTP in Vim?

Tags: vim, ftp, macvim

Using [Vim for FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129864/how-do-i-get-the-standard-vim-ftp-command-to-work) is great, but how do I create files and folders using Vim FTP?

Comment: Not programming related, these are system functions

Comment: Disagree. Creating files and folders is essential to programming.

Comment: As is turning on and setting up a computer, but it's still not programming related

Comment: Hmmm, I've rephrased the question, as I'm looking for a Vim-based solution. This is not a general how-to FTP question. I would imagine it is the interests of this site to cover all Vim features whether you think them related to programming or not.

Comment: Vim is ok on SO. [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-so-or-su)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't know how to create folders via ftp, but you can save files remotely with Nwrite

```
:Nwrite ftp://username@host/path/to/file/andfile.name<cr>
```

use :help netrw-write for all options and protocols

netrw also has

```
MAKING A NEW DIRECTORY                  *netrw-d* {{{2
```

section. read this and it can help to you

Comment: "Currently, making a directory via ftp is not supported."

Answer (score 1):

Newer netrw-s do support making directories via ftp; you should upgrade.  You can get the latest netrw from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW; as of now, its up to v153f.

Comment: I've tried with Vim-7.4.692 and netrw-v154a, but creation of a remote directory over an sftp connection was not successful...the command line freezes and nothing happens: am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but I don't think Vim has the ability to issue FTP commands. Maybe try Emacs…

Or you can log into the remote machine with SSH and do your Vim editing there.

If you want to create directories you can type something like `:! mkdir foldername` to create a directory or `:sh` to launch a new shell while keeping Vim in the background, create your directory, then do `$ exit` to return to Vim.

To save the current buffer to disk, type `:sav filename`.

You can go crazy and use [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to have two windows side by side: one with Vim and the other with a regular prompt.

If you insist on using FTP, you should reverse your workflow to start in the FTP client.  Since you are on a Mac, almost all the FTP clients have an "Edit with…" button that you can configure to launch MacVim.